# Now that we're "big time", did I lose my review privileges?

Tags: support, site-redesign

While we were in beta, I reviewed new posts. Is it just a function of the redesign, or did I lose the ability to review? I'm guessing that now I'm below the level where you can review posts.

I used the "bug" tag only because it's an "unexpected behavior".

Comment: Adding to Pearson's answer, you can [compare the privileges caps in this SO meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).

Comment: @Yisela - Thanks. Interesting some stay the same between beta and full site, while others get bumped up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The reputation required for privileges changes as the site graduates, going quite a bit higher. See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: I suspected so.  Thanks for the quick answer. Now I have to wait 8 minutes to accept it. :)

Comment: Wow, suddenly we only have two trusted users! They don't trust me any more... :'(